# .setOnItemClicklistener not works

Tags: android, android-intent, android-sqlite

I would like to send my data from one activity to other with help of intent and uri but the task doesnt get accomplished

my main activity code

```
package com.example.vidit.inventoryapp;

import android.app.LoaderManager;
import android.content.ContentUris;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.CursorLoader;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.Loader;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;

import static android.R.attr.id;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements    LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

/** Identifier for the pet data loader */
private static final int ITEM_LOADER = 0;

/** Adapter for the ListView */
ItemCursorAdapter mCursorAdapter;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
          Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,editor.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    ListView ItemListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

    // Find and set empty view on the ListView, so that it only shows when the list has 0 items.
    View emptyView = findViewById(R.id.empty_view);
    ItemListView.setEmptyView(emptyView);

    // Setup an Adapter to create a list item for each row of pet data in the Cursor.
    // There is no pet data yet (until the loader finishes) so pass in null for the Cursor.
    mCursorAdapter = new ItemCursorAdapter(this, null);
    ItemListView.setAdapter(mCursorAdapter);

    // Setup the item click listener
    ItemListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
            // Create new intent to go to {@link EditorActivity}
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,editor.class);

            Uri itemUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(ItemContract.ItemEntry.CONTENT_URI, id);

            intent.setData(itemUri);

            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    // Kick off the loader
    getLoaderManager().initLoader(ITEM_LOADER, null, this);
}

private void insertPet() {
    // Create a ContentValues object where column names are the keys,
    // and Toto's pet attributes are the values.
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(ItemContract.ItemEntry.NAME, "Football");
    values.put(ItemContract.ItemEntry.PRICE, 200);
    values.put(ItemContract.ItemEntry.STATUS, ItemContract.ItemEntry.ACCEPTED);
    values.put(ItemContract.ItemEntry.QUANTITY, 7);


    // Insert a new row for Toto into the provider using the ContentResolver.
    // Use the {@link PetEntry#CONTENT_URI} to indicate that we want to insert
    // into the pets database table.
    // Receive the new content URI that will allow us to access Toto's data in the future.
    Uri newUri = getContentResolver().insert(ItemContract.ItemEntry.CONTENT_URI, values);
}

/**
 * Helper method to delete all pets in the database.
 */
private void deleteAllPets() {
    int rowsDeleted = getContentResolver().delete(ItemContract.ItemEntry.CONTENT_URI, null, null);
    Log.v("CatalogActivity", rowsDeleted + " rows deleted from pet database");
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int i, Bundle bundle) {
    String[] projection = {
            ItemContract.ItemEntry._ID,
            ItemContract.ItemEntry.NAME,
            ItemContract.ItemEntry.PRICE,
            ItemContract.ItemEntry.QUANTITY,
            };

    // This loader will execute the ContentProvider's query method on a background thread
    return new CursorLoader(this,   // Parent activity context
            ItemContract.ItemEntry.CONTENT_URI,   // Provider content URI to query
            projection,             // Columns to include in the resulting Cursor
            null,                   // No selection clause
            null,                   // No selection arguments
            null);

}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
    mCursorAdapter.swapCursor(data);

}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
    mCursorAdapter.swapCursor(null);

}
```

}

My adapter class:

```
 package com.example.vidit.inventoryapp;

 import android.content.ContentUris;
 import android.content.ContentValues;
 import android.content.Context;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.database.Cursor;
 import android.net.Uri;
 import android.text.TextUtils;
 import android.view.LayoutInflater;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.ViewGroup;
 import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.CursorAdapter;
 import android.widget.TextView;

 import static android.R.attr.id;
 import static android.R.attr.order;
 import static android.R.attr.value;
 import static android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M;



public class ItemCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
public ItemCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
    super(context, c, 0 /* flags */);
}

public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    // Inflate a list item view using the layout specified in list_item.xml
    return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, final Context context, final Cursor cursor) {
    // Find individual views that we want to modify in the list item layout
    TextView nameTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
    TextView priceTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.price);
    final TextView quantityTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.quantity);
    Button sell=(Button) view.findViewById(R.id.sell);
    Button order=(Button) view.findViewById(R.id.order);
    Button detail =(Button)  view.findViewById(R.id.detail);





    // Find the columns of pet attributes that we're interested in
    int nameColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(ItemContract.ItemEntry.NAME);
    int priceColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(ItemContract.ItemEntry.PRICE);
    int quantityColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(ItemContract.ItemEntry.QUANTITY);



    // Read the  attributes from the Cursor for the current pet
    String itemName = cursor.getString(nameColumnIndex);
    String itemPrice = cursor.getString(priceColumnIndex);
     final String itemQuantity=cursor.getString(quantityColumnIndex);


    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(itemPrice)) {
        itemPrice = "Not known yet";
    }
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(itemQuantity)) {
        itemPrice = "Not known yet";
    }

    final int qua=Integer.parseInt(itemQuantity);
    nameTextView.setText(itemName);
    priceTextView.setText(itemPrice);
    quantityTextView.setText(itemQuantity);

    sell.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(Integer.parseInt(itemQuantity)>0)
            {
                int x=Integer.parseInt(itemQuantity)-1;

                quantityTextView.setText("" + x);
                int idColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(ItemContract.ItemEntry._ID);
                int id = cursor.getInt(idColumnIndex);
                Uri itemUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(ItemContract.ItemEntry.CONTENT_URI, id);
                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                values.put(ItemContract.ItemEntry.QUANTITY, x);
                context.getContentResolver().update(itemUri, values, null, null);
            }

        }
    });





    order.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.fromParts(
                    "mailto","abc@gmail.com", null));
            emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject");
            emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Body");
            context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send email..."));
        }
    });

   /* view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context,editor.class);

            Uri itemUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(ItemContract.ItemEntry.CONTENT_URI, id);
            intent.setData(itemUri);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });*/
}


}
```

if I add intent code which i have commented in adapter class itnet happens succesfully but no data is passed from list view to the intent .

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is there setOnitemClicklistner?? coz you setOnclickListner. in adapter

Comment: yes typo mistake,

Comment: I want to intent from main activity